# Printing to different log file based on connection in Twisted client application

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code for a TCP client in my Twisted application:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log
import time

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        if(self.factory.server_name == 'server1'):
          log.startLogging(open('server1.log','w'))
        else:
          log.startLogging(open('server2.log','w'))
        log.msg("Connected to "+self.factory.server_name)

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        log.msg("Connection is lost " + reason.getErrorMessage())

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        log.msg("Server said: " + data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self,server_name):
        self.server_name = server_name

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        client = EchoClient()
        client.factory = self
        return client

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        time.sleep(10)
        connector.connect()

conn1 = EchoFactory('server1')
conn2 = EchoFactory('server2')

reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000,conn1)
reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8001,conn2)

reactor.run()
```

Now when I run the program I see that **server1.log** has both the `Connected to server1` and `Connected to server2` lines, whereas **server2.log** only has `Connected to server2`.

How can i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having here is that `log.startLogging` is meant to be
called *once* per process lifetime, to open a single log file.  If you think
about it, how is Twisted supposed to know what log file a particular `log.msg`
call should go to in your example?  You're not passing a log file or any
information about which one to use.

There are also a number of things about your example which are using very
old-fashioned Twisted idioms, so I'm going to completely overhaul this example
to use newer Twisted APIs:

1. Rather than using the old and busted `twisted.python.log` module, I'm going
   to use the [new logging hotness](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6750)
   in
   [`twisted.logger`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.logger.html).
2. Rather than use the old and busted `IReactorTCP.connectTCP`, I'm going to
   use
   [Endpoints](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/endpoints.html)
   which have a number of advantages.
3. Rather than importing the reactor and running it directly, I'm going to use
   [`twisted.internet.task.react`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.task.html#react)
   so that I'm relying on the global reactor (which is
   [bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)).

There are also a couple of things that you're doing which were *always* a bad
idea in Twisted:

1. You should never use `time.sleep()` in any Twisted program, ever.  It blocks
   the entire reactor, which means that all outstanding tasks in your Twisted
   program (excepting those in threads) are stopped while you wait for it.
   There are asynchronous APIs, such as
   [`deferLater`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.task.html#deferLater),
   that you can use to deal with the passage of time.
2. You should never use string formatting to put together log messages.
   `twisted.logger` makes this a bit easier and has nicer syntax, but even with
   `twisted.python.log` has always had support for structured data in log
   messages.
3. You have 2-space indents in a couple of places.  For shame :).

I'm going to answer your question by using the Twisted logging system, but
emitting logs from your connections only to dedicated observers.  The reason
that I'm doing this is that it's somewhat tricky to *intercept* log messages
destined for the global log and convince the existing global logging
infrastructure that it *shouldn't* write those messages to the main log file.
This is by design: once logging is set up, it often serves as catch-all that is
necessary to catch the messages leading up to an error.  Another potential
answer would be to simply open a text file from each connection and not involve
Twisted's logging system at all.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import io

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.logger import Logger, jsonFileLogObserver

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    log = Logger()

    def connectionMade(self):
        log = self.log
        log.observer = jsonFileLogObserver(
            io.open(self.factory.server_name + ".json.log", "tw")
        )
        self.log = log

        self.log.info("Connected to {log_source.factory.server_name}")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.log.info("server said: {data!r}",
                      data=data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.log.info("Connection is lost: {reason}",
                      reason=reason)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = EchoClient
    def __init__(self, server_name):
        self.server_name = server_name

from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def main(reactor):
    for portNumber in 8001, 8002:
        endpoint = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", portNumber)
        endpoint.connect(
            EchoFactory("server_" + str(portNumber - 8000))
        )
    return Deferred()

react(main)
```

Note that in `connectionMade`, we get the `Logger` instance with `self.log`,
but since the class attribute `EchoClient.log` is a descriptor, it's creating a
new instance each time.  To ensure that our modified `observer` attribute state
is persisted, we re-assign `self.log` to the resulting object.

This will produce some log files which contain rich structured information, but
may be somewhat hard for humans to read.  If all you really care about is
literal text log files to be read by people, and you don't want to do any log
analysis, you can just use `textFileLogObserver` rather than
`jsonFileLogObserver`; however, with a tiny bit of code, you can get the best
of both worlds.  Here's a very short program that will read one of the log
files produced here and emit classic log text that a person could read or pipe
to grep:

```
import io
from twisted.logger import eventsFromJSONLogFile, formatEventAsClassicLogText

for event in eventsFromJSONLogFile(io.open("server_1.json.log", "rt")):
    print(formatEventAsClassicLogText(event))
```